# Mounting a network folder to a Docker container on Windows 10

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to mount a network folder with a Docker container on Windows 10 with the following syntax. Using UNC paths does not work. I'm running it under Hyper-V and the stable version of Docker.

```
docker run -v \\some\windows\network\path:/some/local/container
```

Before I was using Docker Toolbox, and I could map a network share to an internal folder with VirtualBox. I've tried adding the network share as a drive, but it doesn't show up as an available drive under the settings panel.

Currently I'm using mklink to mirror a local folder to the network folder, but I'd like to not depend on this as a solution.

Comment: Sorry I don't see solution either. Even Hyper-V doesn't have shared folder options

Comment: Still not possible?  So hard to find answers when 90% of search results are focused on Unix containers, even when you include "Windows Containers" in search.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem as well.  Any chance you figured this out?

Comment: I have a windows laptop at home so hopefully can try this within next 24 hours and reply @Russell

Answer (score 7):

### Do this with Windows based containers

Go to  Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/persistent-storage#smb-mounts.

There you'll find information about how to mount a network drive as a volume in a windows container.

---

### Do this with Linux based containers

Is currently (as of 2019-11-13) not possible. **BUT** you can use a plugin: https://github.com/ContainX/docker-volume-netshare

I didn't use it, so I have no experience with it. Just found it during my research and wanted to add this as a potential solution.

### Recommended solution

While researching on this topic I felt that you should probably mount the drive from within the container. You can pass required credentials either via file or parameters.

#### Example for credentials as file

You would require to install the package `cifs-utils` in the container, add

`COPY ./.smbcredentials /.smbcredentials`

to the Dockerfile and then run the following command after the container is started:

`sudo mount -t cifs -o file_mode=0600,dir_mode=0755,credentials=/.smbcredentials //192.168.1.XXX/share /mnt`

---

#### Potential duplicate

There was another stackoverflow thread on this topic here:
[Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows)

The answer provided there (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57510166/12338776) didn't work for me though.

Comment: Could you adjust your answer to be a little more detailed and specific on how this answers the question rather then simply linking to other sources. Thanks

Comment: Using `cifs-utils` worked for me. my base image is `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:centos-7`