# Haven't been able to bind mount a network drive on Docker for Windows

Tags: windows, docker

I'm trying to bind mount a network drive from my host (Windows 10) to a local folder in a container but, regrettably, I haven't been able to achieve it.

In Linux I've had no issues whatsoever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
docker run -v G:/:mnt/shared ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

For local drive, use the following command:

```
docker run -v c:/your-directory/:/mnt/shared ubuntu /bin/bash
```

For network drive, you need to create a Docker volume pointing to that network drive.

The command would be as follows:

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=cifs --opt device=//networkdrive-ip/Folder --opt o=user=yourusername,domain=yourdomain,password=yourpassword mydockervolume
docker run -v mydockervolume:/data alpine ls /data
```

Reference is here: [How to Add Network Drive as Volume in Docker on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help! I ran your command but it didn't work. I got this error:



C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Drive sharing failed for an unknown reason.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.




Any ideas?

Comment: You might have to create a Docker volume, I guess. By the way, I'm glad you found a solution that worked for you.

Comment: thank you! spent almost 2 days looking for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it in a different way.

Here is the answer: [Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57510166/11962716)