# Access a network drive from docker container

Tags: linux, windows, docker, dockerfile, network-drive

How can I access files on a shared network drive from docker container?

I tried:

```
docker run --rm -it --name my_app -v  //shared_drive_name:/opt/local/shared_drive my_app:1.0 /bin/bash
```

Also I tried method mentioned here: [Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows)

The directory `/opt/local/shared_drive` is created but empty. I tried different variations of slashes since the host is win and docker running linux. I am connected to the VPN from the host to access these drives.

Answer (score 2):

I have this script for mounting Windows shared folders in Ubuntu Docker container. You have to copy the script in your image.
Then you should run the container, and after that call these commands:

```
docker exec container_name mkdir -p %shared folder inside docker path%
docker exec container_name /bin/bash /~path to your script~/mount_folder.sh %username% %password% %network_path% %docker_path%
```

For instance:

```
docker exec container_name /bin/bash /~path to your script~/mount_folder.sh "Admin" somePassword //192.168.7.1/shared_folder /data
```

Script is (mount_folder.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

USERNAME=${1}
PASSWORD=${2}
NETWORK_PATH=${3}
DOCKER_PATH=${4}

mount -t cifs -o rw,username="${USERNAME}",password="${PASSWORD}",vers=3.0,nolock $NETWORK_PATH $DOCKER_PATH
```