# WIN: Docker Volume from network shared Server directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, shared-directory

my goal is to get a container which is able to access a server directory. Needed for a python script.
My problem is that I am not able to create a volume where the data is shared.

Server directory got some csv data files, and these files I want to get into the container.
These files will be updated from the Server so it is important that these files are no copys, they should be the same files and a kind of shared folder.

At the moment I was only able to create a connection to the server path.
Docker Version: v19.03.8

May you are able to help?

kind regards,
Lucas

Comment: are you using docker-compose? if yes, please post your compose file to see what it is worng in it

Comment: the docker-compose file is totaly fine when I start it.

Comment: It is only that I want a share volume from the server, and I can not find any good answer for this, for this reason I am askin: How can I share a windows server path with a container?

Comment: [Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows) has a Linux-specific suggestion but hints it might not be possible for Windows containers.  Does that question essentially match what you're doing?

Comment: yes, I saw already this post and thought there might be a way to see the documents inside the folder. The command works but the created volume does not have any input documents. That means there is no way to get it work?