# Need to access Files , Folders on Shared Network drive from Docker container, How to?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to access a shared network drive(e.g. \\sharename\folder) in my office from my app in a docker container. I need to access the files inside this shared drive to convert it to a different format, say like csv to pdf/jpeg. This is my office's general which has GBs of data.

My problem here is , I am unable to volume mount this shared network to my docker container. But I am able to volume mount a local folder(C:\Folder) on to my docker, but I am unable to do a shared drive. I can see the volume mount list on the docker desktop, but mapped folder is empty when using shared path. Any clue?

```
docker run -dt -v "//10.0.0.197/ioashare/REQ10001:/shareddoc"
```

I am trying something like above to mount.

Is this way to access shared network drive from docker? I am just trying volume mount, but if there are any other preferred way, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker add network drive as volume on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50239386/docker-add-network-drive-as-volume-on-windows)